# .htaccess and index.html

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

This is for a Wordpress blog. I can redirect a directory level URL correctly. In this case I want /digests to go to /digests_wp (wp is for Wordpress, and is a virtual directory, or really a Wordpress page that exists in a database). This works:

```
Redirect 301 /digests /digests_wp
```

However, since a lot of hits come in looking for digests/index.html I'd like this to redirect properly too. This does not work.

```
Redirect 301 /digests/index.html /digests_wp
```

Instead I get a Page Not Found error because /digest_wp does not really exist as a proper directory, I guess. In any event I'd like it to ignore looking for index.html and work like in the other redirect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I think it would work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^digests(/index\.html)?$ digests_wp [L,R=301]
```

Or you could try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^digests/?$ digests_wp [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^digests/index\.html$ digests_wp [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Odd, tested it out and it worked for me. Maybe you can elaborate on digest_wp not being a "proper" directory.

Comment: I don't know why the first solution didn't work, but your second one did. Thank you!